# Symfony3 group of the same form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have problem with the group of the same form. 
In controller i create a few form like this

```
foreach($matchEntityList as $entityId => $entityItem) {
     $form[$entityId] = $this->createForm(MatchType::class, $matchEntityList[$entityId], [
         'matchId' => $entityId,
     ])->createView();
}
```

And in view i display each form individual. When i click on submit individual i send id of form in input hidden to controller and i do request on this form.

```
$formId = $request->request->all()['match']['matchId'];
$form[$formId]->handleRequest($request);
if ($form[$formId]->isSubmitted() && $form[$formId]->isValid()) {
   $em->flush($matchEntityList[$formId]);
}
```

Everything works well but i would like to go a one step forward. I need to have one submit button and when i click him i would like to check all the changes and flush it. You have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean one submit button to submit all forms?

Comment: Yes, but it would be perfect to check only form wich have been changed because it is big optimization. I think about hidden field and javascript then change value of this field when i change something and do it request only on that form. But need only one submit form!

Comment: Use javascript (jquery) to perform such kind of tasks. I don't know if the hidden field would work. What if a user enters some data in the form he really wants to submit, but, by error, fills in some fields of another form? You'll end up with two submitted forms. I would try to add required fields for each form, and if one field of an undesired form is filled, then don't submit any form, and display a message to the user, asking the right action.

Comment: Ok, but this optimization is a secondary task. I need have one form with one submit where ever field will have name like match[firstTeam][0] instead match[firstTeam]